# Solving this polynomial equation

Tags: calculus

So I'm trying to maximize a log function and I'm getting stuck in solving for $x$.

The original function is

$$g(x) = x^{-3} \log (1+x^2) + x^{-1} \log(1+x^2) - x^{-1}$$

Note that plotting this in R, I can see a clear maximum close to $e^1$ (though slightly to the right).

The derivative is equal to

$$g'(x) = \log(1+x^2)(-3 x^{-4}-x^{-2})+\frac{2}{1+x^2}(x^{-2}+1)+x^{-2}$$

But setting equal to zero, I'm having trouble separating the logarithm to get a closed form solution of $x_\max$.

Edit: My original line below here was incorrect. Corrected now

This leads to

$$1+x^2 = \exp \left( \frac{3x^2}{3+x^2} \right) $$

Comment: You can not algebraically solve these kinds of equations. You might try a numerical approach.

Comment: Are you sure the derivative is correct? WA provides https://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP2214313h2ff3gac1ch3h400004ihe97h9d5b7gb61?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=53

Comment: Really? Because the question I'm working on seems to suggest you can solve for it

Comment: @raptor the derivative is correct. They're just written in different forms. Double checked by plotting both graphs

Comment: @Xiaomi very well then but IMO perhaps the rearrangement may help? Like I get $1+x^2=\exp \left( \dfrac {3x^2}{x^2+3} \right)$ from the new one whereas you got $1+x^2 = \exp \left( \dfrac{2+x^2}{3+x^2} \right)$. Can you double check your last steps because otherwise seems like $2+x^2=3x^2 \implies 2x^2=2 \implies x^2=1 \implies x=\pm 1.$ which should not be possible.

Comment: After redoing the working I get the same as you. Is there anyway forward from here?

Comment: The graph that you needed is this: 
As you can see, the maximum occurs at $(7.681, 0.10523)$ so I am not sure how you found that it is close to $e^1.$
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCH7p.png

Comment: Desmos and R seem to give different graphs. I can't find where the difference between the two is? R gives this https://imgur.com/a/BuqEAdi and if I plot the same expression in Desmos I get your one. However, manually putting in 2.755 will give you around 0.5, which contradicts the Desmos graph